# leading zeros in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a form where user updates the table in database with serial numbers, the problem is that in my .csv file serial number has value 0 and after inserting it, it has 000000, same for the 1, after inserting it is 000001. I need it in exact way like it is in .csv file. My code for the LOAD is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE path_to_file.csv
INTO TABLE im_seriennummer CHARACTER SET latin1
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (sn,description_sn)
```

In .csv file it is like this:

0

1

And in database

000000

000001

In the database sn is varchar(16).
Is this problem familiar to anyone? Please don't tell me to change the type of field, I need to have it in varchar since some serial numbers are like this MT 002

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE im_seriennummer;

Comment: also provide first few line from CSV if possible, do not upload complete file for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

The solution,i think, is to use a temp table from import the csv.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab LIKE im_seriennummer;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE path_to_file.csv
INTO TABLE tmptab CHARACTER SET latin1
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
        IGNORE 1 LINES
        (sn,description_sn)


UPDATE tmptab SET SERIAL = RIGHT(CONCAT('000000', SERIAL), 6)

INSERT INTO im_seriennummer
SELECT * FROM tmptab

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmptab;
```